# "hidden" type input value, not being send correctly via $_POST

Tags: php, html, post, hidden-field

I was wondering why I am not sending the value of the hidden input? After the browser executes the following code, I actually get the desired ID in the value tag - [see the image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGAJ0.png)

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($allStreets) > 0) {
  while ($display = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allStreets)){
    echo <<< HEREDOC
    <form action="allHouses.php" method="post">
      <table class='table table-striped'>
        <tr>
          <td align="left">
            {$display["name"]}
          </td>
          <td align="right">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="street" value="Go to all houses on this street">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value"{$display['id']}">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </form>
HEREDOC;
  }
} else {
  echo "No streets found";
}
```

And then I have a php code that doest the following:

```
if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
  echo var_dump($_POST['id']);
  echo "set";
} else {
  echo "not set";
}
```

And the output from the var_dump() is: 
**string(0) "" set**.  Not 2 as I expect.
My question is why it is not holding the ID? And how could this be fixed? Thank you!

Comment: Missing `=`, voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `=` in value.

**change this**

```
value"{$display['id']}"
```

**with this:**

```
value="{$display['id']}"
```

Comment: Bloody hell .. 2 hours for this. Thank you sir.